# Are shortcodes the only method of returning HTML?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a Wordpress plugin. And currently I am using a shortcode to output the data. I was wondering if there is any method of displaying the html without shortcodes since a shortcode must be manually entered. I want to enable my plugin and then the html displays by itself? Thanks

Comment: That's why WordPress uses hooks. 'Hook' to an appropriate [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)/[filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) and then output your necessary HTML

Comment: Add the shortcode to your plugin with `do_shortcode()`.

Comment: @George can you expand on this with a simple example I think you are on to it

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for displaying HTML

```
var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  $( this ).text( htmlString );
```